# How to store int with leading Zero in Database with EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, integer

I have integer a with `"10115"` and I able to convert that into string using below code.

```
int a = 10115;    
string sixd = a.ToString("D6");
```

and using this code I able to convert `10115` into `010115`.

but when I convert `010115` into integer using below code but that always convert into `10115` so any trick to convert that into `010115` in `int`.

```
int b = Convert.ToInt32(010115);
```

so any trick to store `010115` into integer ? and same in  `"010115"` format not in 10115 if any one have idea so please help me.

And also I want to store same value in database `"010115"` in column where type is integer.

Comment: Not possible. Numbers cannot have leading zeros, but strings can. You need to transform the value before displaying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can't* have a [leading zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero) for integers. It is only for their string representations.

> When leading zeros occupy the most significant digits of an integer,
>   they could be left blank or omitted for the same numeric value.
>   Therefore, the usual decimal notation of integers does not use leading
>   zeros.

That's why your `Convert.ToInt32(010115);` is equal to `Convert.ToInt32(10115);`

> and also i want to store same value in database "010115" in column
>   where type is integer

That's not possible. If you *really* save it as a `010115`, you *have to* use some character type instead of integer. But I doubt that is a good idea.

[James Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond) has a code number as `007` but *even* he can't save his code number to an integer column without loosing leading zero, how can we?